# Create new objects inside of a function with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

So I want to create a function that if, if a question is answered wrong, it stores the wrong answer into a new object? So that I can list all of the wrong answers at the end?

```
var answerList = [{question:1, answer:1},{question:2, answer:2},]
var listofWrongAnswers = [];

if (answerSelected != answerlist[1].answer) {
    /* create a new object
       put answerlist[1].question and answerlist[i].answer in new object and push to 
       array ListofWrongAnswers */
}
```

I dont get how you can randomly name variables? if that's even possible.

Comment: You don't need to randomly name variables, the index key is the unique identifier in an array

Comment: opps answerSelected belongs to an input value that is checked. but for now we can just say answerSelected = 0;

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you simply create a new object based on the current question?

Something like this should work:

```
if (answerSelected != answerlist[1].answer) {

    listofWrongAnswers.push({question: answerlist[1].question, answer: answerlist[1].answer});
}
```

However, you should look to make that index a parameter:

```
function addToWrongAnswers(answerSelected, idx) {

    if (answerSelected != answerlist[idx].answer) {

        listofWrongAnswers.push({question: answerlist[idx].question, answer: answerlist[idx].answer});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want something like this:

```
function getQuestion(number){
    for(var i = 0; i < answerList.length; i++){
        if(answerList[i].question === number){
            return answerList[i];
        }
    }
}

function checkAnswer(questionNumber, answer){
    var question = getQuestion(questionNumber);
    if(answer !== question.answer){
        listofWrongAnswers[question];
    }
}
```

**However**, I'm also assuming you'll start with Question 1 and increment the number, so it would be even simpler if you just selected the question using an array index, rather than iterating through it. So this might be better:

```
var answerList = [{question:1, answer:1}, {question:2, answer:2}];
var listofWrongAnswers = [];

function checkAnswer(questionNumber, answer){
    var question = answerList[questionNumber - 1];
    if(answer !== question.answer){
        listofWrongAnswers[question];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **clone** that question object and push it into that array, you can use

```
listofWrongAnswer.push({question: answerlist[1].question, answer: answerlist[1].answer});
```

But with this code you won't can use `==` operator to compare question objects existing at those arrays

```
listofWrongAnswer[1] == answerlist[1] // It's false
```

But if you don't want such a behavior you can store only references to question objects in the wrong answer list:

```
listofWrongAnswer.push(answerlist[1]);
```

With this code you can compare question objects with `==` operator

```
listofWrongAnswer[1] == answerlist[1] // It's true
```